# How to understand the relationship between Weinhold geometry and Ruppeiner geometry in thermodynamic geometry?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, differential-geometry, entropy

According to the content of the following paper

[On the relation between entropy and energy versions of thermodynamic
length](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.446467)

The second derivative matrix $D^2 U$ of the internal energy may be used to define a Riemannian structure on the set of
equilibrium states of a thermodynamic system，it was developed by Weinhold.

Ruppeiner has  chosen  to  use  the
Riemmanian structure afforded by $D^2 S$,  the second derivative of the entropy.

These two structures have the following relationship

$D^2 U=-T D^2S $

The left side is the representation in Weinhold geometry, and the right side is the representation in Ruppeiner geometry.

But I don't know how to get it

Example in the paper，however, I still struggle to grasp it well:

Consider the thermodynamic system consisting of
1 mol of an ideal gas

$D^2U(S,V)=\begin{bmatrix}T/C_v&-p/C_v\\-p/C_v&\gamma p/V\end{bmatrix},$

$ D^{2}S(U,V)=\Big[\begin{matrix}{-1/TU}&{0}\\{0}&{-p/VT}\\\end{matrix}\Big],$

$R=\frac{\partial(S,V)}{\partial(U,V)}=\begin{bmatrix}1/T&p/T\\0&V\end{bmatrix},$  $R$ is Jacobian matrix used to transform $D^2 U(S,V)$ to $D^2U(U,V)$

then
$D^2U(U,V)=R^{t}\; D^{2}U(S,V) \;R=\begin{bmatrix}1/U&0\\0&p/V\end{bmatrix}$

$D^2U(U,V)=-T D^2S(U,V)$

My question is as follows

- What does $\gamma$ stand for in $D^2U(S,V)$?
- Why is $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial V} \right)_U=V$ in $R$ (Jacobian matrix)?
- According to the formula, I can only get $D^2U(U,V)=R^{t} \;D^{2}U(S,V) \;R=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{1}{\text{Cv} T} & 0 \\
   0 & \frac{p \gamma }{V}-\frac{p^2}{\text{Cv} T} \\
  \end{array}
  \right)$

Comment: Questions (and answers) should be fully self-contained so that users do not have to download, read & digest links to understand what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide more background information, with more-accessible references.

From a Google search, these seem relevant and more-accessible

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruppeiner_geometry
- (presumably Weinhold's site) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258879552_Thermodynamics_and_geometry

---

*[Update: The answer to two of your questions can be answered without consulting the above references.]*

$\gamma$ is likely the ratio $C_p/C_v$ *(familiar from thermodynamics)*.

Then the matrix element you obtained [from your reference] simplifies to
$$\frac{p \gamma }{V}-\frac{p^2}{C_v T}=\frac{p}{V},$$
using $C_p-C_v=R_{idealGasConstant}$ (the ideal gas constant)
 and the Ideal Gas Law ($PV=nR_{idealGasConstant}T$) *(both familiar from thermodynamics)*.

Comment: R is the Jacobian matrix $R=\frac{\partial(S,V)}{\partial (U,V)}$ in the $2\times 2$ transformation $D^2(S,V) = R^T D^2(U,V)R$

Comment: @hyportnex Um, yes. That's why I wrote "$R$ (the ideal gas constant)" for disambiguation. I will instead use $R_{idealGasConstant}$ for further disambiguation. (I guess one has to read the paper to see why, of all of the familiar symbols used in thermodynamics, $R$ has been chosen to be used for something else.)

Comment: If I take the Jacobian matrix $R=\frac{\partial(S,V)}{\partial(U,V)}=\begin{bmatrix}1/T&p/T\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, $ That is to say that  $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial V}\right)_U=1 $.  and then $D^2U(U,V)=R^tD^2U(S,V)R=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{\text{Cv}T}&0\\0&\frac{p\gamma}{V}-\frac{p^2}{\text{Cv}T}\end{array}\right) $Then I understood the problem according to the explanation you gave $ \gamma $.